# Simplest way to add one class or another

Tags: handlebars.js

With Handlebars, what's the simplest way to add one class or another to each element being rendered by an `{{#each ...}}` helper? I have to integrate with an existing CSS setup for a site, which requires adding one class or another to alternating elements in a list.

Example helper:

```
{{#each items}}
<div class="{{what here?}}">...</div>
{{/each}
```

...where we want `even` or `odd` as the class names. (Yes, again, I know this can be done with CSS; I'm integrating with an **existing** site's CSS, which uses alternating classes instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Handlebars newbie, I'm not seeing anything built-in, but the API makes it pretty easy to add a helper that lets you select from an arbitrary-length list of items, like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('cycle', function(index) {
    index = index % (arguments.length - 2); // -2 to leave out `index` and the final argument HB adds
    return arguments[index + 1];
});
```

Using that it would be:

```
{{#each items}}
<div class="{{cycle @index 'even' 'odd'}}">...</div>
{{/each}
```

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('cycle', function(index) {
  index = index % (arguments.length - 2); // -2 to leave out `index` and the final argument HB adds
  return arguments[index + 1];
});

var items = [
  "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"
];

var template = Handlebars.compile(
  document.getElementById("template").innerHTML
);

var html = template({items: items});

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  html
);
```

```css
.even {
  color: blue;
}
.odd {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each items}}
<div class="{{cycle @index 'even' 'odd'}}">{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Or if I wanted three classes in rotation:

```
{{#each items}}
<div class="{{cycle @index 'one' 'two' 'three'}}">...</div>
{{/each}
```

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('cycle', function(index) {
  index = index % (arguments.length - 2); // -2 to leave out `index` and the final argument HB adds
  return arguments[index + 1];
});

var items = [
  "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"
];

var template = Handlebars.compile(
  document.getElementById("template").innerHTML
);

var html = template({items: items});

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  html
);
```

```css
.one {
  color: blue;
}
.two {
  color: green;
}
.three {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each items}}
<div class="{{cycle @index 'one' 'two' 'three'}}">{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```